# Using interface in Fragment - android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I create a `Interface` like bellow:

```
interface LevelsViewListener {
    fun isVisible()
}
```

and in my `activity` is:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    var levelsViewListener: LevelsViewListener? = null

    fun initTEST(listener: LevelsViewListener){
        this.levelsViewListener = listener
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        (context as MainActivity).levelsViewListener


         btnClick.....{
                levelsViewListener!!.isVisible()
          }
    }
}
```

And in my `fragment` is:

```
class LessonsFragment : Fragment(), LevelsViewListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as MainActivity?)?.initTEST(this@LessonsFragment)
    }
}
```

But get me bellow error in `LessonsFragment` :

[image]

Comment: do you think that any of the answers below helped to figure out the issue? if so, please consider to accept one

Answer (score 0):

If a class implements two interfaces (or, let's say, implements one interface and extends one class, as in your case), and each interface defines a method that has an identical signature, then in fact there is only one method, and they are not distinguishable. If, say, two methods have conflicting return types, then it will be a compilation error. This is what happens in your fragment class.

The problem is that the Fragment class also has an `isVisible` function, but it returns `boolean`. And your `isVisible` function in LevelsViewListener returns `Unit`.
There are two solutions to this problem.

1. You should return boolean in your `isVisible` function in LevelsViewListener interface.
2. You can change the name of the function in LevelsViewListener interface

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `isVisible()` function is already defined as part of the `Fragment` class. As reported in the error message the signature is:

```
final public boolean isVisible()
```

and its return value is boolean. Conversely, your interface `LevelsViewListener` defines a method with the same name but without return value. This scenario is not allowed by Java/Kotlin.